# C++ Entering Multiple Values into Element of 2D Array

Tags: multidimensional-array

my question is regarding entering information into elements of an array. I have created a [2][3] array and now am attempting to add an age, id, and salary to each element of the array. The very bottom of my code I tried setting the values in my first element of the array and it underlines "employeeArray"  and says expression must have a value type. Now I am fairly certain that I am setting the values correctly so I am wondering if I am missing some of initialization, pointer, etc somewhere else in my code. I attached the complete code below

```
class Employee
{
  private:
  int age;
  int id;
  float salary;
  public:
  Employee()
{
    age = 0;
    id = 0;
    salary = 0;
}

void setAge(int x)
{
    age = x;
}
void setId(int x)
{
    id = x;
}
void setSalary(float x)
{
    salary = x;
}
int getAge();
int getId();           
float getSalary();

};

int Employee::getAge()
{
  return age;
}
int Employee::getId()
{
   return id;
}
   float Employee::getSalary()
{
   return salary;
}



int main()
{   
const int rows = 2;
const int columns = 3;

int employeeArray[rows][columns];
employeeArray[0][1].setAge(30);
employeeArray[0][1].setId(111);
employeeArray[0][1].setSalary(30000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare you multidimensional array you are declaring an array of ints.
This:

```
int employeeArray[rows][columns];
```

Should probably be more like:

```
Employee employeeArray[rows][columns];
```

Ints will not respond to the .setAge and other functions as they are not part of that types class.

Cheers